# Parse string in a specified format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

my string :

```
var json_d = "{0:'apple', 1:'bannana', 2:'guava'}";
```

I want this string to parse via json in this format using javascript:

```
var json_d = {
  columns: [{0:'apple'}, {1:'bannana'} ,{2:'guava'}]}
```

I have tried this code to convert it, but I did'nt able to...

```
json_d = JSON.parse('{"columns": [{"":""}]}')
```

Comment: Your string is not JSON. The input is essentially broken; fix whatever's generating it to serve you JSON instead

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"columns": [{"":""}]}')` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try parse your string:

```
JSON.parse(json_d.replace(/(\d+)\:/g,'"$1":').replace(/'/g,'"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [documentation of the JSON schema](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), we can see that your original string does not meet the definition of JSON:

Original string:

```json
{0:'apple', 1:'bannana', 2:'guava'}
```

This is incorrect for a couple of reasons:

1. Object keys must be strings (You cannot use the number `0` or `1`, but you could use the string `"0"` or `"1"`)
2. Strings must be surrounded by double quotes `"`

Possible correct JSON for your data:

```js
{"0":"apple", "1":"bannana", "2":"guava"}

// Wrap this in another type of quotes for Javascript
var json_d = `{"0":"apple", "1":"bannana", "2":"guava"}`;
// Or escape the double quotes
var json_d = "{\"0\":\"apple\", \"1\":\"bannana\", \"2\":\"guava\"}";
```

Or:

```
["apple", "bannana", "guava"]

// Wrap this in another type of quotes for Javascript
var json_d = `["apple", "bannana", "guava"]`;
// Or escape the double quotes
var json_d = "[\"apple\", \"bannana\", \"guava\"]";
```

Hint: There are good JSON validators online, such as: https://jsoneditoronline.org/